Why is pandas rounding different from python rounding?
It stumbled upon a case where Pandas and Python behave differently when rounding.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> numbers = [0.495,1.495,2.495,3.495,4.495,5.495,6.495, 7.495,8.495, 9.495, 10.495]
>>> [round(float(x),2 ) for x in numbers]
[0.49, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.49, 9.49, 10.49]
>>> pd.DataFrame(numbers).astype(float).round(2)
        0
0    0.50
1    1.50
2    2.50
3    3.50
4    4.50
5    5.50
6    6.50
7    7.50
8    8.49
9    9.49
10  10.50

Why does Pandas round 0.495 and 10.495 different to Python? I thought since Python 3 both implemented banker's rounding? Is one implementation more correct than the other?

I suspect one is using single precision and the other is double precision.

Check the notes at np.round: "[it] uses a fast but sometimes inexact algorithm to round floating-point datatypes, ... [while] Python’s builtin round function uses a more accurate but slower algorithm for 64-bit floating point values."

Looking into Pandas internals, it uses ndarray.round() to accomplish the rounding, which is equivalent to np.round(): https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/fdcdcb84cfa675b756c7f4c42d3eb466c49bc098/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py#L1516

The answer was basically given by the comment from @ouroboros1. It turns out that Pandas is using uses np.round under the hood. And the documentation of np.round() mentions, that :

"[it] uses a fast but sometimes inexact algorithm to round floating-point datatypes, ... [while] Python’s builtin round function uses a more accurate but slower algorithm for 64-bit floating point values."

I just want to elaborate on what "inexact" means in our example. If we sum the numbers of the example without rounding we get
>>> sum(numbers)
60.445

If we sum the numbers rounded by Pandas we get
>>> pd.DataFrame(numbers).round(2).sum()
0    60.48

And if we sum the numbers rounded by Python we get
>>> sum([round(x, 2) for x in numbers])
60.46

So in case of doing computations with several rounded numbers the rounding algorithm of Python delivers a result closer to the exact result than using the Pandas rounding function.
However to get even closer to the exact result you should only round at the end of your computation
>>> pd.DataFrame(numbers).sum().round(2).  # better than round(2).sum()
0    60.44

But also in this case the best/expected result is given by Python round() function
>>> round(sum(numbers),2)
60.45

To summarize: Round as late as possible in your calculation. Prefer Python round() function over Pandas rounding if you aim for precision and not speed.
UPDATE: It seems my conclusion were a bit to hasty. If we really aim for precision we should use the decimal package of Python.
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP, ROUND_HALF_EVEN
>>> [round(Decimal(str(x)),2) for x in numbers]
[Decimal('0.50'), Decimal('1.50'), Decimal('2.50'), Decimal('3.50'), Decimal('4.50'), Decimal('5.50'), Decimal('6.50'), Decimal('7.50'), Decimal('8.50'), Decimal('9.50'), Decimal('10.50')]
>>> sum([round(Decimal(str(x)),2) for x in numbers])
Decimal('60.50')

We see here that the correct sum of over rounded numbers is 60.50, so actually Pandas rounding is closer to that. But this is an accident. Basically the error due to the floating point representation and the error due to the inexact rounding of numpy cancel each other leading to a result closer to the exact result using the decimal class. If we instead round after summation we get
>>> round(sum([Decimal(str(x)) for x in numbers]),2)
Decimal('60.44')

This happens because round() uses ROUND_HALF_EVEN (Bankers rounding) by default for Decimal objects. So again Pandas seems closer to that result. However this is again due to the cancelation of the inexact floating point representation and the inexact rounding algorithm. If we use ROUND_HALF_UP with Decimal we get the result we got with Python round():
>>> sum([Decimal(str(x)) for x in numbers]).quantize(Decimal("0.01"), ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('60.45')

So why does Python rounding returning the result for ROUND_HALF_UP, if it uses Bankers rounding (ROUND_HALF_EVEN) by default? This is because of the inexact floating point representation of the sum in combination with the exact rounding algorithm:
>>> Decimal(60.445)
Decimal('60.44500000000000028421709430404007434844970703125')
>>> round(Decimal(60.445),2)
Decimal('60.45')

But
>>> Decimal(str(60.445))
Decimal('60.445')
>>> round(Decimal(str(60.445)),2)
Decimal('60.44')

So it seem that the inexact Pandas/Numpy rounding algorithm can sometimes cancel the effect of the inexact floating point representation leading to results closer to the exact result using the decimal package. The Python round() function is - in some sense - too exact and will magnify problems caused by the inexact representation of floating point numbers.
UPDATE2: It seems the final result in this example not only depends on the rounding algorithm. It turns out that Pandas and Python are also summing floating point numbers slightly different, see Why is do Pythons sum() and Pandas sum() yield different results
